# Number combinations.

Tags: probability, solution-verification, dice, fake-proofs

A fair die with faces numbered $1, ... , 6$ is thrown repeatedly. I want to figure out the probability that at least one 4 and at least one 5 occur before the first 6.

Before I start, I have looked at the mark-scheme and I understand the method they have used but with this question I am to understand where **I** am wrong.

My approach:

I want to figure out what is the complementary probability. The probability that there will be none $4$s and no $5$s before the first $6$ is

$$q_1= \frac{1}{6}+ \frac{3}{6}\frac{1}{6} + (\frac{3}{6})^2\frac{1}{6} + \cdots = \frac{1}{3}$$

The probability that there will be all $5$s (or similarly all $4$s) before the first 6 is

$$q_2=\frac{1}{6^2}+\frac{1}{6^3} + \cdots =\frac{1}{30}.$$

And thus the complimentary probability to the desired one is $$\frac{1}{3}+2 \times\frac{1}{30}=\frac{6}{15},$$

where the two comes from the fact that there is the scenario of all $4$s before a $6$ aswell. It follows that the desired probability is then

$$1-\frac{6}{15}=\frac{3}{5}.$$

However, the markscheme says he answer should be $\frac{1}{3}$. I assume I am wrong in my calculation of there beeing only of one type of number before the 6 but I don't see exactly where I am wrong. Could somebody assist me on this?

Comment: You have the complement incorrect. The 'opposite' of at least one 4 and one 5 before the 6 is not none of either. For instance, if I get all 4's before the 6, that's fine because I didnt get any 5's.

Comment: Hi @mathematics2x2life, thank you for the comment. I have already calculated the probability of that occurring, see the calculation for getting all 5's, as it is the same for all 4's

Comment: No, you haven't quite. Remember, there are other numbers! For instance, 4,4,4,4,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,3,4,2,6 is in the complement. I could have rolled 1,1,1,1,6 and be in the complement. There are far more combinations than you have counted because you have only focused on the 4,5's. [This is why the answer is too large. You haven't 'complimented' enough out.]

Answer (score 1):

The complement event you want is that we either have zero $4$s or zero $5$s rolled before the $6$ is rolled. If we let $A$ be the event that no $4$s are rolled before the $6$ is rolled and $B$ be the event that no $5$s are rolled before the $6$ is rolled, then the probability we are after is $$1-P(A\cup B) = 1-P(A) - P(B) + P(A \cap B)$$

Can you take it from here?